# Can Javascript save values of variables to external source?

Tags: javascript

I will try to be succinct.

I am a teacher and we are all currently teaching online. I caught a **lot** of students cheating last semester in the online homework system I use and I know it is because I refuse to use Proctorio (it is terribly invasive).

All I want (as far as proctoring capability) in the questions I code into this online homework system is the ability to know when a student navigates away from the digital assignment. I am getting closer with the help of some wonderful people here, however, I have just a little bit more to go.

Here is the modified code. The event listeners work fine, but I want to press that single button on the page and it is just not working. The button does not have an ID or a name, but the innerHTML is always " Submit Question ".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myWindow
  window.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    refocusWindow();
  })
  window.addEventListener("focus", function(){
    myWindow.removeEventListener("blur", refocus);
    myWindow.close();
  })
  function refocusWindow(){
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow");
    myWindow.document.write("<h1>During this assessment, you are not allowed any resources other than what is provided within the assessment. Going to another website, tab, page, or application is considered cheating. This event has been logged. Return to the assessment at this time or further actions will be taken!</h1>");
    myWindow.addEventListener("blur", refocus);
  }
  function refocus(){
    myWindow.close();
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (document.visibilityState != "visible" || document.hidden){
        refocusWindow();
      }
    },1)
  }
  function clickButton() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("primary");
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if(buttons[i].type == 'button' && buttons[i].innerHTML == " Submit Question ") {
        buttons[i].click();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The class name of the button is "primary", so that's why I am searching for that.

Comment: Have a server and make a fetch/XHR request to it when detected.

Comment: Try using some sort of storage system, such as the document's cookies.

Comment: I don't think cookies would work in this case. For what I'm thinking, the best approach would be as @CertainPerformance mentioned: send requests to a server and store in a database

Comment: How are you communicating their answers to the homework questions? There has to be a remove server somewhere that those get sent to in real time right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do not have access to a server to store the information. I suppose the best option for information delivery is a summary email.

Comment: I don't think sending an email from the client-side is easily doable. Unless you already have something set up for that, it could be difficult, and will be a security risk regardless. A server would really be a much better choice, some places offer them for free

Comment: @codemonkey I have no control over the remote server (it is an open-source online homework system). My only true hope of capturing this information and delivering it back to me is to somehow log it while the student is taking the assessment (which is what my code above does) and send that to me via email or some other means (which my code does not do).

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it's actually quite easy to set up an email system, once you get the hang of it. Getting the hang of it is the difficult part.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options (evercookies, server, etc.), and the best option that I can think of WITHOUT a server is to simply prevent the user from leaving the tab. In addition to this, you might have to add a system that emails you the results when the tab is closed, because if you don't, the user can close the tab knowing the questions, and then cheat on it, and then just type in the answers. You can also include a google sign in to make sure that it is the student who is answering the question.

Anways, enough talk - here's how to prevent them from leaving the site. Note that this probably won't work on an online text editor, so you have to create an HTML file on your computer, copy and paste the code, and then open it locally on a browser (drag the file from File Explorer, if you use windows, or from something else, depending on what you use). To see it in action, simply leave the tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname">

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

<script>
var myWindow
window.addEventListener("blur", function(){
refocusWindow()
})
window.addEventListener("focus", function(){
myWindow.removeEventListener("blur", refocus)
myWindow.close()
})

function refocusWindow(){
myWindow=window.open("", "myWindow")
myWindow.document.write("<h1>Please return to the HW - no cheating!</h1>")
myWindow.addEventListener("blur", refocus)
}

function refocus(){
myWindow.close()
setTimeout(function(){
if (document.hidden){
refocusWindow()
}
},1)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that you can also integrate full screen mode with this which takes the user to a full screen mode whenever `keydown` is fired or `click/mousedown/mouseup` is fired.

Also, part of your code can be shortened to be more concise.
Replace this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("primary");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  if(buttons[i].type == 'button' && buttons[i].innerHTML == " Submit Question ") {
    buttons[i].click();
    break;
     }
  }
```

With this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("button.primary")].some(function(element){if(element.innerHTML===" Submit Question "){element.click(); return true}})
```

The query selector selects a button with the class primary, the [...] converts the HTMLCollection to a list, the .some loops through the elements until it reaches the element with the innerHTML of " Submit Question ", and clicks it. After that, it returns true so it stops there and doesn't loop through the rest.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("button.primary")].some(function(element){if(element.innerHTML===" Submit Question "){element.click(); return true}})
```

```html
<button class="primary">Don't select</button>
<button class="primary" onclick="alert(1)"> Submit Question </button>
<button class="primary" onclick="alert(1)"> Submit Question </button> <!--Don't select-->
<!--The bottom isn't selected, as there is only 1 alert.-->
```

Comment: I like this solution. There are a couple of issues, however. First, if the student has a completely different browser window open, this process opens a new tab in the original browser window, but the student can still search for solutions in the secondary window. Second (and related), is that the student might have a solution manual saved as a PDF on their computer. This process would only open a new tab and warn them, but they could still access that PDF.

I suppose the warning is almost enough to scare most students, but I still would love a way to send a log of the lost focus to me.

Comment: I fixed the new window issue, but unfortunately I cannot do much about the PDF. (`document.visibilityState!="visible"` to `document.hidden`). The best option I can think of to _send_ you a report automatically is to use the Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), but it's complicated to set up (took me much more than several tries to set up one with the Classroom API).

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the time and thought experiment. I am curious, is there a way to have a pop-up that requires a specific code to remove? That is, everything works the way your code does above, but once the student goes back to their assignment, it requires a code. This would force them to contact me (I proctor all exams synchronously, so it would just require a single question in our Zoom chat), and would thus inform me of their moving away from the window/tab.

Comment: That's going to be really difficult to implement without a server of some sort. The best thing I can think of is to create a random number or string, hash it using a SHA algorithm, and store it in an evercookie, while sending the unhashed version to your computer somehow. Then, when checking it, rehash the input code and check against the stored evercookie to confirm if it is correct or not.

Comment: The hashing is necessary because otherwise a student could just look at a website's cookies using `document.cookie`. SHA encryptions cannot be decoded except by brute force. I would recommend SHA-256, since that is the most secure (to be honest, I don't know why, but that's what it says everywhere).

Comment: Hmm... it sounds like it might be easier to get the Javascript to just submit the student's work ("click submit") once they navigate away thereby using one of their tries. They have a limited number and, since I am proctoring the exam, they would easily be able to contact me to increase the number of tries on their specific question (assuming an accidental navigation away or that some other program stole the focus).

Comment: Just curious, how would you 'increase the number of tries'? I can only think of using a server for this kind of 'increasing', since otherwise students can do it just as easily and it won't be secure.

Comment: It's on the backend. As an instructor, I can reset or increase the number of tries for an individual student. By the way, I updated the code (see the original post) and am now looking at clicking the " Submit Question " button. That extra bit of code I added broke things.

Comment: I edited my post above really quick, because a part of your code could be shortened to a one-liner.

Comment: Thank you. I think there is just an issue of my lack of knowledge here. I inspected the element (button) and it returned the following: <div class="submitbtnwrap"><input type="submit" class="primary" value="Submit"></div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227114/discussion-between-endothermic-dragon-and-roy-simpson).